# Set callback function in directive angular2

Tags: callback, directive, angular

I tried use the componente in angular2 as directive. This is code the directive:

```
export class Datepicker {
    public date : Date;
    public callback : Function;

    constructor() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
            nextText: 'Próximo',
            prevText: 'Anterior',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                console.log(this.callback);
            }
        });
    }

    setCallback(fn : Function){
        this.callback = fn;
    }
}
```

In html:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input datepicker" [(ng-model)]="datepicker1" type="text"/>
```

In my componente use this code:

```
import {Component, NgIf, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ElementRef} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Datepicker} from '../datepicker/datepicker';

declare function initMaterial();

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    directives: [NgIf, Datepicker, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: './frontend/components/modal/modal.html',
    styleUrls: ['./frontend/components/modal/modal.css'],
    bindings: [Datepicker]
})

export class Modal {
    public isOpen : boolean = false;
    private dtCompromise : Date;
    private dsCompromise : String;
    private datepicker : Datepicker;

    constructor(datepicker : Datepicker){
        this.datepicker = datepicker;
        this.datepicker.setCallback(function(selectedDate : Date){
            console.log('Date: ' + selectedDate);
        });
    }
}
```

In html:

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <datepicker callback="selectDate" [(ng-model)]="datepicker"/>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dtCompromisse">Data</label>
    </div><br>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "5" [(ng-model)]="dsCompromise"></textarea>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dsCompromisse">Descrição</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

When selected date function onSelect is called and console.log print undefined

```
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
   console.log(this.callback);
}
```

Whats is my error?

Comment: Also check it out this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328652/angular2-pass-callback-function-to-child-component-as-input/35329009#35329009

Answer (score 0):

**I.** Use [`ViewChild`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L353) to specify concrete datepicker element and then `setCallback` in [`afterViewInit`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.ts#L378) lifecycle method.

```js
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker'
  // ...
})
export class Datepicker {
  // ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  directives: [NgIf, Datepicker, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  // ...
})
export class Modal {
  //...
  @ViewChild('dp') datepicker : Datepicker;

  afterViewInit() {
    this.datepicker.setCallback(function(selectedDate : Date){
      console.log('Date: ' + selectedDate);
    });
  }
}
```

and template is:

```html
<form action="#">
    // ...
    <datepicker #dp callback="selectDate" [(ng-model)]="datepicker"/>
    // ...
</form>
```

**II.** `this` inside `onSelect` function doesn't refer to the datepicker object. To fix it you have three options:

1. Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method to change context of function execution:

```js
export class Datepicker {
  // ...
  constructor() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      // ...
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        console.log(this.callback);
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
}
```

2. Initialize `var self = this` outside of the `onSelect` callback and then use `self` inside it.

```js
export class Datepicker {
  // ...
  constructor() {
    var self = this;
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      // ...
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        console.log(self.callback);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

3. Use [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you're using ES6:

```js
export class Datepicker {
  // ...
  constructor() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      // ...
      onSelect: (selectedDate) => {
        console.log(this.callback);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not work. Edit my example in question. 
it seems there is no link between html <datepicker/> and models construtctor ( datepicker : Datepicker )

Comment: When run constructor method this not set callback in object of view. This set in other instance of Datepicker

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try to use `ViewChild` annotation

Comment: After  @ViewChild('dp') datepicker : Datepicker; variable datepicker is undefined

Comment: In the html put as: <datepicker #dp callback="selectDate" [(ng-model)]="datepicker"/>

Comment: `undefined` is in `onInit` callback??

Comment: In onInit datepicker is undefined when print console.log(datepicker);

Comment: Ooh, not `onInit`, try `afterViewInit`

Comment: In afterViewInit console.log(datepicker) print null

Comment: Strange, try `@ViewChild(Datepicker)`

Comment: Have you specified that `Datepicker` is directive using `Component` or `Directive` annotation ?

Comment: Using component as example in my question