# Angular2 transform model for custom select Component

Tags: angular, components, ngmodel

In my angular2 app i'd like to have a reusable select component which, in a first draft, looks like this:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-select',
    template: `
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="selectionChanged()">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" name="choose" value="choose">choose ...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of selectModel" [ngValue]="opt">
                {{opt}}
            </option>
        </select>
    `
})
export class SelectComponent {

    @Output()
    changed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    selectModel: any[] = [];

    selectedValue: any = 'choose';

    selectionChanged() {
        this.changed.emit(this.selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this works only with an Array of strings as Input Parameter, since

```
{{ opt }}
```

would only print out `[Object object]` for other types. And thus, the EventEmitter will only emit strings.
Now, what I'd like to have is a component, that I can use similar like this:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

export class Foo {
    bar: string;
    id: number;
    userFriendlyString: string = `id=${this.id}|bar=${this.bar}`;

    constructor(bar: string, id: number) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Component({
    template: `<my-select [selectModel]="model" (changed)="handle($event)"></my-select>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    model: Foo[] = [new Foo('first', 1), new Foo('second', 2)];
    handle(foo: Foo): void {/* ... */}
}
```

My intentions:

1. tell the `my-select` component, that the shown values should be the `userFriendlyString` property of `Foo`. I don't want to hardcode that, since other components should be able to use `my-select` as well with other model classes. I can't imagine how to do that. My first Approach was to have a callback function as `@Input()` for the `my-select` component, but that doesn't work and shouldn't be done [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620352/7774006). The second Approach was to override toString in `Foo`. Doesn't work neither (I assume something like missing dynamic dispatch in `any`...?!).
2. get the `EventEmitter` work as 'expected': it should be possible to have a correct `foo: Foo` in the handle function.

So, is there hope for me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what I would do is create a common interface that components could map their objects to such as:

```
export interface SelectListObject{
    key: string;
    value: any;
}
```

Then use this as the input type on your select list component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-select',
    template: `
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="selectionChanged()">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" name="choose" value="choose">choose ...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of selectModel" [ngValue]="opt.value">
                {{opt.key}}
            </option>
        </select>
    `
})
export class SelectComponent {

    @Output()
    changed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    selectModel: SelectListObject[] = [];

    selectedValue: any = 'choose';

    selectionChanged() {
        this.changed.emit(this.selectedValue);
    }
}
```

This way there is a common interface all your components can use and using `ngValue` in the `option` element lets you emit entire objects as values.

You know your other data models best, but you might be able to put the map function in your `@Input` of the select component so each component doesn't have to transform it's data before sending it into the `SelectComponent`:

```
internalSelectModel: SelectListObject[] = [];
@Input('selectModel')
set selectModel(value){
    this.internalSelectModel = value.map(x => <SelectListObject>{key: value.name, value: value};
}
```

The `handle` function will be unique to each component that uses the `SelectComponent` and thus the value can be whatever type you need(sent in).

Hope that helps.

Comment: works like a charm :)
I had something like this in mind as well, but the two parts of the Interface, `key` and `value` were the missing thing

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this, use `$event` so you can return the value and anything else you want and set the input to take array of objects with the display and value perhaps :-

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

interface selectModel {
    display: string;
    value: any;
}

@Component({
selector: 'my-select',
template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" name="choose" value="choose">choose ...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let opt of selectModel" [ngValue]="opt.value">
            {{opt.display}}
        </option>
    </select>
`
})
    export class SelectComponent {

    @Output()
    changed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Input()
    selectModel: selectModel[];

    selectedValue: any = 'choose';

    selectionChanged(event) {
        let response = {
            value: event.target.value,
            foo: "something else"
        }
        this.changed.emit(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of the same as the above...  
But I like the common Interface for Input and output

Comment: Ah I think I answered like 2 mins after him :) Glad you solved your issue.