# In Angular can I use @Input as event emitter

Tags: javascript, angular

I like to explore the feasibility with using component Input as Event output, similar to how react does it.

*Parent component*

```
parentHandler(message){
   console.log(message)
}
```

*Parent html*

```
<child [myEvent]="parentHanlder"></child>
```

*Child component*

```
@Input myEvent

ngOnInit(){

this.myEvent('hello')

}
```

I am wondering if there are disadvantage or potential issue with this approach e.g memory/performance

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Component input function that takes parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012662/angular-5-component-input-function-that-takes-parameters)

Comment: Not quite. I am aware that input and output both works, I want to know if there is potential issue with using @input only to handle event

Comment: can you please explain why you need this?

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly as expected.

The behavior will be similar to `@Output` **except the context of execution.**

The scope of execution will be with child component

```
export class AppComponent {
 version: number = 7;
  messageMe(param){
    alert("Message Me.."+param+this.version); 
  }
}

<framework
[messageHandler]="messageMe"></framework>


export class FrameworkComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  messageHandler: Function;

  name="Jone";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageHandler(this.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how these works I wonder is there any drawback with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use setter in this situation

Parent:

```
<child [myEvent]="parentHanlder"></child>
```

Child (ts):

```
@Input()
set myEvent(parentHandler: string) {
     this.myEvent('hello');
}
```