# Not able to access method from parent to child in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am not able to fetch another method of parent which is called in method of parent that i am using as input and calling in child component.

```
export class TreeMapComponent {

  data;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let results=[1,2,3]

  }
  fetchChildrenForPage(page, pagePerPage) {
    let results={soemthing: 898, children: [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,5,3,3,4]}
    this.data = { ...results, children: results.children.slice(1, 5) };
    this.createTest(this.data);
  }


  createTest(clusterInfo): void{
      console.log(clusterInfo)
   }
}
```

TreeMapComponent.html (html that i am using for above component, rough idea)

```
<app-sub-custom-pagination[fetchChildrenForPage]="fetchChildrenForPage">
  </app-sub-custom-pagination>
```

Now i will mention the child component `app-sub-custom-pagination`

```
export class SubCustomPaginationComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input()
  fetchChildrenForPage;
  currentPage;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
   selectPage(0);
}

selectPage(index): void {
    this.currentPage = (index + 1);
    this.fetchChildrenForPage(this.currentPage, this.quantityPerPage);
  }
```

But unfortunately i am getting an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.createTest is not a function
.
.
.
```

Comment: Try removing this. Only call createTest(this.data)

Comment: Or you can use @output directive, in subCustomPagination.ts than you can get that event in treeComponent.html using this sysntax.. (fromSubComponet)= "fetchChildrenForPage"

Comment: I can't do that. This is miniaturized form of that method. this.createTest contains another set of 5 6 methods that are part of that parent class. Which is why i need more subtle solution.

Comment: I agree with GaurangDhorda. If the children data is going to be used at TreeMapComponent, then you should go for the @Output directive. A similar topic was discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328652/angular-pass-callback-function-to-child-component-as-input-similar-to-angularjs

Comment: Is'nt that @Output is for child to parent communication?  I have to get this work, I cannot directly call that createTest. Otherwise now solution for me is to use this component directly as html into parent component, which i am trying not to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a parent method from child component the this context inside ferchChilderForPage will be refer to child component

**Example**

```
fetchChildrenForPage(page, pagePerPage){
    console.log(page, pagePerPage, this); //this will refer to child component When you call from child
   //  this.createTest('ClusterInfo');
  }
```

**Try this**

Pass parent instance to child component then call the parent method from child component

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-demo [appInstance]="this"></app-demo>
```

**parent.component.html**

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() appInstance;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(){

    this.appInstance.fetchChildrenForPage('demo','demo2');
  }

}
```

Or

Use [ViewChid](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to access parent component instance from child

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-this)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `fetchChildrenForPage` function in `SubCustomPaginationComponent` which it does not have `createTest` function that makes sense to me.
Try to remove `createTest` Function and just use console.log or define `CreateTest` Function in `SubCustomPaginationComponent`

Comment: I didnt get it. What exactly is not making sense? I am sending `fetchChildrenForPage` to child component, later which child component runs `fetchChildrenForPage`. Bt `fetchChildrenForPage` contains another method that is part of same `parent function`

Comment: `fetchChildrenForPage` Contains function that is referenced to `this` and `this` here in this situation refers to   `SubCustomPaginationComponent`, not to its parent.
and `SubCustomPaginationComponent` does not have this method.

Comment: ohh got it. Perfectly makes sense. I don't know how else to pull this. Real this.chartTest() method contains lots of method from parent component itself.